# Persisting HashMap with Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a class similar to this one:

```
public static class Stats implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;        
    @Persistent(serialized = "true", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    private Map<String, Integer> requests;

    public Stats() {
        requests = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }
}
```

However, Appengine complains that `HashMap is not a supported property type.`

How then it is possible to store a "HashMap" with Appengine? Is there any other workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at EmbeddedEntity. It's not on the official Javadoc yet but will be soon. See [1.6.6 SDK pre-release announcement on AE group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine/8zmSKSYJC_o/discussion).

Another solution could be to serialize your map into a Blob property, e.g.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream writer;

try {
   writer = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
   writer.writeObject(requests);
   writer.close();

  Blob requestsMapAsBlob = new Blob(out.toByteArray());

} catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO: handle exceptions 
}
```

You can then restore the map from that blob with `readObject()`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using JDO.  See the [supported](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses?hl=pl#Collections) JDO collection types. You could consider whether your data could be represented using one of those supported collection types instead, or you could store your HashMap as a serialized field.

Comment: could you update the supported types in that doc since I added support for Map types in v2.x of the datanucleus-appengine JDO/JPA plugin, some time ago.